# Canon PowerShot SX410IS

Tags: canon, powershot, digital-zoom

When you first turn the camera on it does not focus properly and is blurred.  When the lens is fully extended the lens then retracts itself and switch's off it.

Comment: What's your actual question here?

Comment: Charge or change your camera battery.